# Accessing Resources inside SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have developed a `syncadapter` class as specified on the [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).

I am frequently sending data to the server using `onPerformSync()` every 1 hour. The problem I am facing is I am not able to use `getResources().getString(R.string.domain_name)` or `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.port)` to access my resources from inside `onPerformSync()`.

I wanted to know if there is a way to access these resources available in the `/res` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to get `Application Context` which may be useful through out your Application.

Code Snippet:-

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {
private static MyApp instance;
public MyApp() {
    instance = this;
 }
public static Context getContext() {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Now you could use Application Context to get your resources throughout your application which means inside your `performSync()` too.

```
  MyApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.domain_name)
```

You need to add your `Application class` inside your `<application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <application
    android:name="com.example.MyApp"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: I already tried that, but the domain_name doesn't even come up in suggestions. You can get suggestions till R.string. only.

Comment: @Roadblock : If `domain_name` means your resources not coming up in suggestion that means your `R.java` is not getting generated. It's Auto generated file. Please check your `Error Log` if using eclipse. Try to check your `/res` error folder for auto generating `R.java`.

Comment: All I ever hear about this is that you shouldn't do it, I do it and I feel really guilty about how easy it makes things- you can have static function that returns the instance, ```public static Application app(){return instance;}``` and then anywhere you need a context in your application you can pretty much just call ```app()```, but I can pretty much guarantee that this is a horrible and bad thing to do